# Selecting Columns Based on Case or If Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wan't to display columns based on conditions/parameters
what i want is

```
if(@SelectFlag==true)
    select name,Address,salary,CreatedBy from employee
else (@UpdateFlag==true)
    select name,Address,salary from employee    
    -- in this case i don't require the column "CreatedBy"
```

How can i make a query or stored procedure looking at the above circumstances..

Thanks & regards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single `=` and `1` instead of `true`.

```
if @SelectFlag = 1
  select name, Address, salary, CreatedBy from employee
else
if @UpdateFlag = 1
  select name, Address, salary from employee
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example for creating stored procedure, maybe you need to have only one parameter that indicates what are you trying to do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedurenameHere(@EventFlag INTEGER)
AS
    -- @EventFlag
    -- 1 for SELECT
    -- 2 for UPDATE
    IF @EventFlag = 1
        SELECT  name,Address,salary,CreatedBy 
        FROM    employee
    ELSE IF @EventFlag = 2
        SELECT  name,Address,salary, NULL AS CreatedBy 
        FROM    employee
GO
```

execution:

```
EXEC procedurenameHere 1
```

Comment: Please pass two parameters to your procedure, else it will throw error `@SelectFlag` and `@UpdateFlag` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Table : emp
Columns : name, address, salary, creditedBy

```
declare My_Block
    p_select_flag emp.SelectFlag%type;
    p_updateFlag  emp.UpdateFlag%type;
BEGIN
    select selectFlag into p_select_flag from emp where name='ASIF';
    select update into p_updateFlag from emp where name='ASIF';

IF p_select_flag = 'TRUE' THEN
    select name,Address,salary,CreatedBy from employee;
ELSIF UpdateFlag = 'TRUE' then
    select name,Address,salary from employee;
END IF;

END My_Block
```

Answer (score 0):

U can call inside the SP with parameter and pass one parameter as FLAG as Integer:

Use single = and 1,2 instead of true.

1 INDICATE FOR SELECT AND 2 INDICATE FOR UPDATE

```
if @FLAG = 1
  select name, Address, salary, CreatedBy from employee
else
if @FLAG = 2
  select name, Address, salary from employee
```